# Query String protection for ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: security, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, query-string, code-injection

I am using visual studio 2015 and for my homework i am tasked with ensuring that the query strings are protected. I understand that in ASP.NET MVC 5 the query strings are already protected, so is there a way to make the query string unprotected so that it would be prone to query string injections from page to page?

Comment: You may want to write sql using string concatenation with query parameter (in the controller action) and then pass in malicious query parameter to simulate SQL injection: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/how-sql-injection-can-be-possible-in-asp-net-websites/

Comment: @varinder hey the link was really healpful, however i am using ASP.NET v5 which does not include a aspx file, so is there any other solutions ?

Comment: How about creating an action method that executes SQL and accepts a parameter which can be passed via url?